# VSCode Snippet - Dynamically generating characters based on user input length

Tags: html, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I have this basic snippet for vue-html

```
{
    "BANNER1": {
        "prefix": "banner",
        "body": ["<!-- ----------------", "/// $1", "--------------------- -->"]
    }
}
```

It render this

```
<!-- ----------------
/// ADD VALUES 
--------------------- -->
```

Right now, I hardcoded 16 dashes `-`

Can I dynamically generate the amount of `-` based on my $1?

Let's say, I enter "Hello" which contains 5 characters

I'm hoping to get this

```
<!-- -----
/// Hello
----- -->
```

Comment: You already answered this mark.

Comment: @jD3V I tried the snippet from the accepted answer of that link you shared. It is not getting what I expected. I got 3 things the same. The replacement seems to never happen. Please see this : https://i.imgur.com/gKazcE9.png

Comment: I added extra bonus content to this answer about varying the lengths with a new regex.

Comment: Both answers were authored by Mark, and both questions are conceptually the same. To further my argument, I didn't know much about snippets — _I actually disable them all together in my suggestions widget_ — but for the sake of knowing I used the other answer to learn how to do it. Its a solution to this question. If you feel I am wrong, edit your question and ensure that it is conceptually different, or explain why it doesn't answer your question, but saying I tried the answer, it doesn't work, is not enough.

Comment: Actually, it takes very little different content in either answer to satisfy most people that both answers have value.  I did that here for getting variable-length tabstops which is interesting and uses a conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
"BANNER1": {
  "prefix": "banner",
  "body": [
    "<!-- ${1/./-/g}",
      "/// $1", 
      "${1/./-/g} -->"
  ]
}
```

`{1/./-/g}` will replace each character in `$1` with a `-`.  In that way you are effectively counting the number of characters in `$1`.

[image: snippet length of input]

---

What if you wanted to add one less than the length of `$1`, then use this:

`"<!-- ${1/^.|(.)/${1:+-}/g}"`

The first character, the `.` is not captured in a regex group.  So if you wanted to use the length-2 you would change the first part to `^..` so `${1/^..|(.)/${1:+-}/g}` or generically

`${1/^.{n}|(.)/${1:+-}/g}`

and replace that `n` with whatever number you want to subtract from the `$1`.

The rest of tabstop $1 is matched one by one (thanks to the global flag). And then the conditional

`${1:+-}` says if there was a capture group 1, then add a `-`.  Capture group 1 itself is never added to the replacement.

Comment: I used your code, and my result shows 3 things the same.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/MXEOvyr.png

Comment: You have to hit `Tab` one more time to complete the transform.  All transforms, these things: `${1/./-/g}` are a `transform`.

Comment: Can we please skip the tab part ? make it work automatically as soon as I finished typing ... If not possible, I understand.

Comment: Not possible in built-in vscode to not use the final tab to complete a snippet transform.  You could look at the extension `Hypersnips` which can be made to do it automatically.